# r markdown equation cannot knit correctly in Word 2016

Tags: r-markdown, equation

I had a strange situation. The temperature equation cannot be knitted correctly in a Word document (Word 2016), while the other equation works just fine. I am showing the screenshots and hoping to have suggestions about what is wrong here. I appreciate any help. :-D

The equations in the Word output:
[image]

The equation shows in RStudio:

[image]

The equation shows in HTML output:
[image]

Here I used a generic script to test the equation codes.

````
---
title: "test_equation"
date: "9/16/2020"
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

The equation doesn't show in the Word:  

$$\Delta Temperature = \frac{\Delta Heat}{Density\times{Specific}\space{Heat}\times{\Delta Flow}\space{Volume}}$$

-------------------------------------------
The equation shows in the Word:
$$ME = \frac{1}{n}\sum(X_{sim} - X_{obs})$$
````

Comment: It would be helpful to post the R code you're ysing so other people can try to reproduce the same error. Screenshots aren't very helpful.

Comment: Thanks, @Werner! I added the codes to my question. I used the RStudio new R markdown template. The script can be knitted to both Word and HTML. In HTML, the temperature equation and the ME equation both work fine. But only the ME equation shows correctly in Word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the `\space` that caused the problem. `\text` works when adding spaces in equation.

Correct equation code:

```
$$\Delta Temperature = \frac{\Delta Heat}{Density\times \text {Specific Heat}\times \Delta \text {Flow Volume}}$$
```

Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343701/how-do-i-add-spaces-when-im-doing